# java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild

Tags: groovy

I am newbie to groovy script. I have jenkins job which has groovy being used for pipeline.

I'm trying to read the XML file using XmlSlurper class and capture the required information within it so that I can supply those to the next command.

I was able to capture the information, however when I try to input captured values to the next command which run based on the values it being supplied, it throwing an error. Below is the details,

My groovy script:

```
env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
def setting = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/settings.xml"
def pkgXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(setting)
def hostUrl = pkgXml.profiles.profile[0].properties['sonar.host.url']
sh("node_modules/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner scan -e -Dsonar.host.url="+hostUrl+" -Dsonar.language=js '-Dsonar.projectName=Test angular project analyzed with the SonarQube Runner' -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.projectKey=testpipeline_02 -Dsonar.sources=src -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/base/dir/ -Dsonar.buildbreaker.skip=true")
```

Error message:

```
[BFA] Done. 0s
an exception which occurred:
    in field locals
    in field caller
    in field e
    in field program
    in field threads
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@2ff2da03
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
```

Im expecting to pass the values captured from XmlSlurper, to the sonar scanner command.

Thanks in advance and in anticipation with resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing `pkgXml.profiles.profile[0].properties['sonar.host.url']` is not returning the property value, but an object that cannot be serialized.  Have you tried the following:

```
def hostUrl = pkgXml.profiles.profile[0].getProperty('sonar.host.url')
```

Comment: It returns ( pkgXml.profiles.profile[0].properties['sonar.host.url'] ) the desired value. It looks something related to serialization but I am not sure about fix.

You suggestion gives empty value. Thanks